# How to form strings in php

Tags: php

I have an table, Now i want when after filling this table
This is the table in `ssl.php` page

```
<table  width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr> 
            <td class="TitleBar">Generate CSR</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     <table  cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">

         <tr>               
            <td>Country Name(only two letters) :</td>
            <td >
            <input name="countryname" type="text"  id="countryname" MaxLength="2"/>
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>                
            <td>State or Province Name :</td>
            <td> 
            <input name="province" type="text" id="province"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>               
        <td>Locality Name :</td>
            <td >
            <input name="localityname" type="text"  id="localityname"/>
            </td>
        <tr>                
        <td>Organization Name :</td>
            <td> 
            <input name="organizationname" type="text" class="style16" id="organizationname"/>
            </td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>           
         <td>Organizational Unit Name :</td>
                <td > 
                <input name="organizationunit" type="text" id="organizationunit"/>
                </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>               
        <td>Common Name :</td>
            <td> 
            <input name="commonname" type="text"  id="commonname"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
            <tr>                
        <td>Email Address :</td>
            <td > 
            <input name="email" type="text"  id="email"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:15px padding-bottom:10px" align="right"> 
             <input name="gencsr" type="submit"  id="button" value="Generate CSR" class="FormButton" />
            </td>

            </tr></table>
```

HERE is my inputs :-

```
Country Name(only two letters) :IN
State or Province Name         :MAHARASHTRA
Locality Name                  :MUMBAI
Organization Name              :Cofin Inc
Organizational Unit Name       :Sales
Common Name                    :www.coufdffin.itdpl
```

I want my output like this :-

```
"/C=IN/ST=MAHARASHTRA/L=MUMBAI/O=Cofin Inc/OU=Sales/CN=www.coufdffin.itdpl"
```

How can i make the string in this format after post the table

```
UPdate
```

now i am using this

```
$dn = array("C" => "".trim($_POST['countryname']),
   "ST" => "".trim($_POST['province']),
   "L" => "".trim($_POST['localityname']),
   "O" => "".trim($_POST['organizationname']),
   "OU" => "".trim($_POST['organizationunit']),
   "CN" => "".trim($_POST['commonname']),
   "emailAddress" => "".trim($_POST['email']));
   $comma_separated = implode(",", $dn);
   echo $comma_separated;
```

What can i do plz help me?

Comment: Do you have any HTML or PHP code that you're working on?

Comment: @Kevin Hikaru Evans:) Question edited

Comment: You'll have to tell us more about the exact boundary conditions. Is this input literally what you receive? And will the field names always remain the same? Also: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @fireeyedboy :) Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
$dn = array("C" => "".trim($_POST['countryname']),
   "ST" => "".trim($_POST['province']),
   "L" => "".trim($_POST['localityname']),
   "O" => "".trim($_POST['organizationname']),
   "OU" => "".trim($_POST['organizationunit']),
   "CN" => "".trim($_POST['commonname']),
   "emailAddress" => "".trim($_POST['email']));
   $comma_separated = implode(",", $dn);
   echo $comma_separated;
```

do:

```
$dn = array("C" => "".trim($_POST['countryname']),
"ST" => "".trim($_POST['province']),
"L" => "".trim($_POST['localityname']),
"O" => "".trim($_POST['organizationname']),
"OU" => "".trim($_POST['organizationunit']),
"CN" => "".trim($_POST['commonname']),
"emailAddress" => "".trim($_POST['email']));
$str = '';
foreach($dn as $key => $val){
    $str .= "/$key=$val";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make (C,ST,L,O,OU,CN) in one array, ang get the post array after the page posted,

construct the new string using implode() method.

Answer (score 0):

If these fields in your html form named correctly. you can simple "add" all these string together. Let's say the name of Country Name field in form is *countryname*. The PHP can then read the input *IN* with `$_POST["countryname"]`. So you can generate the first session of your output like this

```
$output = "/C=" . $_POST["countryname"]
```

Use . to connect different strings in PHP.

Hope this help. :)